# Compile chromium on ubuntu 18.04, ninja subcommand failed

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium, ninja, gn

I tried to write a ctf topic - GoogleCTF2018_Just-In-Time(browser pwn). I tried to compile chromium on linux platform, but there is an error.  According  to the build.sh file, I used the following command on terminal. GoogleCTF2018_Just-In-Time topic :
https://github.com/google/google-ctf/tree/master/2018/finals/pwn-just-in-time

```
mkdir chromium
cd chromium
fetch --nohooks chromium
cd src
build/install-build-deps.sh
gclient runhooks
git fetch --tags
git checkout tags/70.0.3538.9
gclient sync
gn gen out/Default
gn args out/Default
```

in out/Default

```
use_jumbo_build=true
enable_nacl=false
remove_webcore_debug_symbols=true
use_goma = true
is_debug = false
```

```
cd  /home/myname/Downloads/v8
git apply ../GoogleCTF2018_Just-In-Time/addition-reducer.patch
cd  /home/myname/Downloads/chromium/src/
git apply ../../GoogleCTF2018_Just-In-Time/nosandbox.patch
ninja -C out/Default chrome
```

Then, the error happened…

```
ninja -C out/Default chrome
directory : /home/myname/Downloads/chromium/src/
```

error :

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[1/22610] CXX obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o
FAILED: obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o 
/home/myname/goma/gomacc ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"340925-1\" -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=332543 -DCR_LIBCXXABI_REVISION=331450 -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=815a8c22f8657fe57d02e2c2d893bcdc25a243cf -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -I../.. -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -funwind-tables -fPIC -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -no-canonical-prefixes -fcomplete-member-pointers -m64 -march=x86-64 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path -Wno-user-defined-warnings -Wno-unused-lambda-capture -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-enum-compare-switch -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang enforce-in-thirdparty-webkit -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-enum-max-value -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -std=c++14 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++ -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++abi/trunk/include --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../base/base_switches.cc -o obj/base/base_static/base_switches.o
/bin/sh: 1: /home/myname/goma/gomacc: not found
[2/22610] CC obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/evutil.o
FAILED: obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/evutil.o 
/home/myname/goma/gomacc ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/evutil.o.d -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"340925-1\" -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=332543 -DCR_LIBCXXABI_REVISION=331450 -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=815a8c22f8657fe57d02e2c2d893bcdc25a243cf -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -I../../base/third_party/libevent/linux -I../.. -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -funwind-tables -fPIC -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -no-canonical-prefixes -fcomplete-member-pointers -m64 -march=x86-64 -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang enforce-in-thirdparty-webkit -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-enum-max-value -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path -Wno-user-defined-warnings -Wno-unused-lambda-capture -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-enum-compare-switch -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -std=c11 --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -c ../../base/third_party/libevent/evutil.c -o obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/evutil.o
/bin/sh: 1: /home/myname/goma/gomacc: not found
[3/22610] CC obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/http.o
FAILED: obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/http.o 
/home/myname/goma/gomacc ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/http.o.d -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"340925-1\" -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=332543 -DCR_LIBCXXABI_REVISION=331450 -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=815a8c22f8657fe57d02e2c2d893bcdc25a243cf -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -I../../base/third_party/libevent/linux -I../.. -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -funwind-tables -fPIC -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -no-canonical-prefixes -fcomplete-member-pointers -m64 -march=x86-64 -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang enforce-in-thirdparty-webkit -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-enum-max-value -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path -Wno-user-defined-warnings -Wno-unused-lambda-capture -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-enum-compare-switch -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -std=c11 --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -c ../../base/third_party/libevent/http.c -o obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/http.o
/bin/sh: 1: /home/myname/goma/gomacc: not found
[4/22610] CC obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/log.o
FAILED: obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/log.o 
/home/myname/goma/gomacc ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/log.o.d -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"340925-1\" -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=332543 -DCR_LIBCXXABI_REVISION=331450 -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=815a8c22f8657fe57d02e2c2d893bcdc25a243cf -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -I../../base/third_party/libevent/linux -I../.. -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -funwind-tables -fPIC -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -no-canonical-prefixes -fcomplete-member-pointers -m64 -march=x86-64 -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang enforce-in-thirdparty-webkit -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-enum-max-value -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path -Wno-user-defined-warnings -Wno-unused-lambda-capture -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-enum-compare-switch -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -std=c11 --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -c ../../base/third_party/libevent/log.c -o obj/base/third_party/libevent/libevent/log.o
/bin/sh: 1: /home/myname/goma/gomacc: not found
[7/22610] ACTION //base:base__jumbo_merge(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have already installed ninja & depot_tools. And added paths to ./bashrc. I think the following error is the key reason, but I can’t find a useful solution......

```
ACTION //base:base__jumbo_merge(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
```

Comment: `/home/myname/goma/gomacc: not found` - what is this tool? Is this some compiler? Is this installed?

Comment: Goma is used for developers of google.I think…… It is not neccessary for this case…?

Comment: Why is it not necessary? Ninja throws an error stating it couldn't find that tool.

Comment: I found th error. In this file "gn args out/Default"-->use_goma = false.
It will work.

Comment: FYI Goma is a distributed compilation service for Chrome and Android, that's not needed for indie developers building their own Chromium fork.

Comment: Also why are you building way outdated version of Chromium? You should try to stick with the latest stable version because of stability and security fixes